# Error loading gazebo in Virtualbox

Tags: ros, gazebo, cturtle, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am new to ROS and trying to work with the simulator for the DARPA ARM Robot.  I am using cturtle on a virtual machine running 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04 (as specified in the installation instructions for the ARM simulator at http://thearmrobot.com/trac/wiki/ARMSimulatorInstallation).

When I try to test Gazebo by using roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch, I get the following:

Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:261 : Exception: Error loading the GUI
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 1832, exit code -11].
log files: /home/scott/.ros/log/b5485c98-9ec2-11e1-8b13-080027314ab6/gazebo-2*.log

The graphics card is an ATI Radeon HD 5450. I have successfully used roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch using fuerte on a virtual machine running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on the same computer.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to help?  Thanks and let me know if there is any additional information that would be helpful.

EDIT: I saw this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/12527/gazebo-2-process-has-died-pid-25662-exit-code-11 but I do not have a /tmp/gazebo folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34091/error-loading-gazebo-in-virtualbox/) by [otto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2387/otto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing guest additions (on Virtual Box menu, choose Device/ Install Guest Additions) let me use Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [otto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2387/otto/) with karma: 46 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-16**:
@otto That is cool ! I thought that gazebo may not work at all in a Virtual OS as it has issues interfacing the graphics memory.

**Comment by [Amer Al-Radaideh](https://answers.ros.org/users/29188/amer-al-radaideh/) on 2017-03-11**:
Have you succeeded on running gazebo on VirtualBox?